# Flattening Parent Child JSON Array with Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array that look like the below.

```
const arr = [{
  name: 'x',
  type: 'type1',
  parent: [{
    name: "a",
    type: 'type1'
  }]
}, {
  name: 'y',
  type: 'type1',
  parent: [{
    name: "b",
    type: 'type1'
  }]
}];
```

I want to flatten this and end up with a result that look like this:

```
const arr = [{
  name: 'x',
  type: 'type1',
  parent-name:'a',
  parent-type: 'type1'
  },
  {
  name: 'y',
  type: 'type1',
  parent-name: 'b',
  parent-type: 'type1'
}];
```

I have tried various different solutions using map and array.prototype.flat() but can't quiet get it to work. I will never have more than one child and if there were to be a second child then I am fine that it creates 2 rows from this.

Thanks
Michael

Comment: I guess you will need to create a new array and map over each object and use Object.entries to use the parent key/value to create new object properties and then delete parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to use [Map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```
result = arr.map(obj => {
  obj.parent.forEach(item => {
    Object.keys(item).forEach(value => {
     obj["parent-" + value] = item[value];
    });
  });

  delete obj.parent;

  return obj;
});
```

**Live Example:**

```js
const arr = [{
  name: 'x',
  type: 'type1',
  parent: [{
    name: "a",
    type: 'type1'
  }]
}, {
  name: 'y',
  type: 'type1',
  parent: [{
    name: "b",
    type: 'type1'
  }]
}]

result = arr.map(obj => {
  obj.parent.forEach(item => {
    Object.keys(item).forEach(value => {
     obj["parent-" + value] = item[value];
    });
  });
  
  delete obj.parent;
  
  return obj;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Isn't this answer specific only for the array `arr` in this question? What if `parent-name` has another object as it's child?

Comment: @VermaJr. - Yes, this solution wouldn't handle the case if `name` has a child object. But OP has explicitly mentioned that the data wouldn't have more than one child ever.

Comment: Ohh, I didn't notice this.

Answer (score 0):

This will flatten any JSON array upto Level 2, as you asked.

```
Object.flatten = function(data){
    var resultMain = [];
    var result = {};
    function recurse(cur, prop){
        if (Object(cur) !== cur){
            result[prop] = cur;
        }else if(Array.isArray(cur)){
             for(var i=0, l=cur.length; i<l; i++)
                 recurse(cur[i], prop);
            if(l == 0)
                result[prop] = [];
        }else{
            var isEmpty = true;
            for(var p in cur){
                isEmpty = false;
                recurse(cur[p], prop ? prop+"-"+p : p);
            }
            if(isEmpty && prop)
                result[prop] = {};
        }
    }
    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        result = {};
        recurse(data[i], "");
        resultMain[i] = result;
    }
    return resultMain;
}
```

**Object.flatten() in action:**

```js
const arr = [{
  name: 'x',
  type: 'type1',
  parent: [{
    name: "a",
    type: 'type1'
  }]
}, {
  name: 'y',
  type: 'type1',
  parent: [{
    name: "b",
    type: 'type1'
  }]
}];

Object.flatten = function(data){
    var resultMain = [];
    var result = {};
    function recurse(cur, prop){
        if (Object(cur) !== cur){
            result[prop] = cur;
        }else if(Array.isArray(cur)){
             for(var i=0, l=cur.length; i<l; i++)
                 recurse(cur[i], prop);
            if(l == 0)
                result[prop] = [];
        }else{
            var isEmpty = true;
            for(var p in cur){
                isEmpty = false;
                recurse(cur[p], prop ? prop+"-"+p : p);
            }
            if(isEmpty && prop)
                result[prop] = {};
        }
    }
    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        result = {};
        recurse(data[i], "");
        resultMain[i] = result;
    }
    return resultMain;
}

console.log(Object.flatten(arr));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I accepted the answer from Nikhil as its less code and simpler for me to understand as a newbie but this is also a correct answer and looks to be a very flexible solution.